# Spacing in Material UI grid not working as expected

Tags: layout, grid, material-ui, spacing

Here is my Sandbox for this question: https://codesandbox.io/s/gridspacing-x2fy3?file=/src/Home.jsx

The layout is almost looking how I want it to; however, I would like to be able to adjust spacing between the components within the inner column `Grid`. Right now, even though I put `spacing={4}` on line 45 in `Home.jsx`, it makes no difference whatsoever if I take that line out or replace the value with some number other than 4. I expected the spacing between the components in that `Grid` to change dependent on that value.

What am I doing wrong and how should I fix it to be able to adjust spacing? Thank you.

Comment: In order for the spacing to have an effect, the children need to be Grid items.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thank you! I will definitely try that. Would you please so kind as to point me toward any documentation on this?

Comment: https://material-ui.com/api/grid/#props - spacing - "Defines the space between the type `item` component. It can only be used on a type `container` component."